# Maximum call stack size exceeded when filling a square of only 10 by 10 pixels

Tags: javascript, canvas

I know that with the method I want to perform, only small shapes can be filled. But I want to fill a small square but still get a stack overflow error.
Why it happens?
Maybe I have problems with functions `color()` or `setcolor()`?

```js
function func() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("image");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 100;

  var width = 10;
  var height = 10;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var imagedata = context.createImageData(width, height);
  var pixelindex = (y * width + x) * 4;

  function color(x, y) {
    let pixelindex = (y * width + x) * 4;
    return imagedata.data[pixelindex] + "," +
      +imagedata.data[pixelindex + 1] + "," +
      +imagedata.data[pixelindex + 2] + "," +
      +imagedata.data[pixelindex + 3];
  }

  function setcolor(x, y, cn) {
    let colors = cn.split(",");
    let pixelindex = (y * width + x) * 4;
    imagedata.data[pixelindex] = colors[0];
    imagedata.data[pixelindex + 1] = colors[1];
    imagedata.data[pixelindex + 2] = colors[2];
    imagedata.data[pixelindex + 3] = colors[3];
  }

  function fill4(x, y, cb = "27,94,32,255", cn = "67,160,71,255") {
    if (color(x, y) !== cb && color(x, y) !== cn) {
      setcolor(x, y, cn);
      fill4(x, y - 1, cb, cn);
      fill4(x, y + 1, cb, cn);
      fill4(x - 1, y, cb, cn);
      fill4(x + 1, y, cb, cn);
    }
  }

  fill4(5, 5);

  context.putImageData(imagedata, x, y);
}
```

```html
<body onload="func();">
  <canvas id="image"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: perhaps `color(x, y) !== cb && color(x, y) !== cn`  is always true - since you build the return value with `v1, v2, v3, v4` and check for `v1,v2,v3,v4` it will be

Comment: The bounding case of your recursion has no spaces in it, but the strings you are comparing to do.

Comment: `fill4` is recursive, so it'll keep calling that until the stack is full. I suggest running it in your browser's debugger and tracking those calls.

Comment: Consider using a standard serialization like [`JSON.stringify`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) if you must.

Comment: @Bravo I corrected the code but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: There are 4 recursion calls... Even if the first (`fill4(x, y - 1, cb, cn);`) succeeds, then the second (`fill4(x, y + 1, cb, cn);`) starts. On every iteration `setcolor` is called to change the very same pixel all the time. It just can be endless. It would fail even on a *1px x 1px* canvas.

Comment: for a start, I'd use something like `if (y) fill4(x, y - 1, cb, cn, rec+1);` no point in filling `(x, -1)` -

Comment: What prevents your code from going outside of the ImageData's boundaries? Waking up but to me it seems this does grow infinitely.

Comment: The x and y variables used in that eternal loop are `5` for `x` and `5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ...` and so on for `y`... The first recursion fails already,

Comment: as simple `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height) return;` as the first statement in `fill4` will fix it

Comment: or `if (x >=0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height && color(x, y) !== cb && color(x, y) !== cn) { ..... }`

Comment: Look for [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) anyway... Since that is the issue: a misuse of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all the comments under my question, I rewrote the code a bit. Most importantly, I added the conditions that I was told about. Without these conditions, my function ran indefinitely, which is why the error was received. Now, by executing the code, you can see the correct filling of the square with the selected color.

```js
    function func() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("image");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    var width = 100
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var zX = 50;
    var zY = 50;
    
    var cb = [27,94,32,255];
    var cn = [67,160,71,255];

    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeRect(x, y, width, width);

    if (zX > x && zX < x + width && zY > y && zY < y + width) {
        fill4(zY, zY, cb, cn, context);
    }
    function fill4(zX, zY, cb, cn, content) {
        var imagedata = context.createImageData(1, 1);
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            imagedata.data[i] = cn[i];
        }
        var color = context.getImageData(zX, zY, 1, 1).data;
        if (zX > x && zX < x + width && zY > y && zY < y + width) {
            if (color[0] != cn[0] && color[1] != cn[1] && color[2] != cn[2] && color[3] != cn[3]) {
                context.putImageData(imagedata, zX, zY);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    fill4(zX, zY-1, cb, cn, context);
                    fill4(zX, zY+1, cb, cn, context);
                    fill4(zX-1, zY, cb, cn, context);
                    fill4(zX+1, zY, cb, cn, context);                            
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

```html
<body onload="func();">
  <canvas id="image"></canvas>
</body>
```